# save button not excuting in console with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to store data by using ajax but in network console... after clicking Button ADD CHARGE, nothing is happening.

Here is my button HTML code and ajax code.

```js
function saveCharge() {
          
            var charge_per_order = $('#charge_per_order').val();
               alert(values);
            $('#saveCharge').modal('show');
               alert(values);
            $.ajax({
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
                url: "{{URL::to('api/saveCharge')}}",
                data:{'charge_per_order':charge_per_order},
                method:'POST',

                success: function( resp ) {
                    $('#saveCharge').modal('hide');
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function( req, status, err ) {
                    console.log( 'something went wrong', status, err );
                }
            });

        }
```

```html
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#saveCharge" onclick="saveCharge();">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>  Add Charge
            </a>


    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="saveCharge" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="saveCharge">Add Charge</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                                           <form id="saveCharge" name="saveCharge" >
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 form-group">
                                chargeperorder: <input type="text" name="charge_per_order" class="form-control"><br>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <a  href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return saveCharge();" value="" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

when i clicking at save button on pop modal,nothing is happen. i have also controller perfect with store method in jason data api.

Controller :

```
 public function saveCharge(Request $request)
{


    $country_id = $request->country;
    $exchange_id = $request->exchange;
    $market_id = $request->market;
    $brokerage_company_id = $request->brokerage_company;
    $charge_intraday = $request->charge_intraday;
    $charge_delivery = $request->charge_delivery;
    $charge_per_lot = $request->charge_per_lot;
    $charge_per_order = $request->charge_per_order;


    $data = array(
        'country_id'=>$country_id,
        'exchange_id'=>$exchange_id,
        'market_id'=>$market_id,
        'brokerage_company_id'=>$brokerage_company_id,
        'charge_intraday'=>$charge_intraday,
        'charge_delivery'=>$charge_delivery,
        'charge_per_lot'=>$charge_per_lot,
        'charge_per_order'=>$charge_per_order,

    );
    //  DD($data);
    $res = UserProfile::where('user_id', Auth::user())->create($data);

    echo json_encode($res);
}
```

ADDING here my console screen:
[image: console]

COSOLE ERROR:

> Uncaught TypeError: saveCharge is not a function
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (profile:347)

Comment: put this in your `ajax url` put this `{{ url('api/saveCharge')}}`

Comment: I done this, but  my ajax not excuted on clicking save button @darksihart

Comment: Do you get any errors in your console?  If it's not alerting, there should at least be some error there or some indication of what's happening.

Comment: actually there is not error in console, just click on save but its not closing.. nothing happening. @user3158900

Comment: Let me add here my controller for you @user3158900

Comment: I have added screen of console @user3158900

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a malfunction with your function, just rename it to something like saveChanges()

I think it's because of the name and id of your form. So change the name and id of your form or change the function name.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>TEST</title>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>
 <body>
 
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="javascript:void(0);" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#saveChargeModal" onclick="saveCharges();">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>  Add Charge
            </a>


    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="saveChargeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="saveChargeHeading">Add Charge</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                                           <form id="saveChargeForm" name="saveChargeForm" >

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3 form-group">
                                chargeperorder: <input type="text" name="charge_per_order" class="form-control"><br>
                            </div>

                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return saveCharges()">Save changes</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
function saveCharges() { 

            var charge_per_order = $('#charge_per_order').val();
               alert("11111");
            $('#saveChargeModal').modal('show');
               alert("22222");
            $.ajax({
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
                url: "{{URL::to('api/saveCharge')}}",
                data:{'charge_per_order':charge_per_order},
                method:'POST',

                success: function( resp ) {
                    $('#saveChargeModal').modal('hide');
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function( req, status, err ) {
                    console.log( 'something went wrong', status, err );
                }
            });

        }

</script>

 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have updated id and name also now... nothing is happening

Comment: I have changed the code a little bit. Check it out again. It works for me (with alerts and without data).

Comment: i found the error in console `Uncaught TypeError: saveCharge is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (profile:347)
onclick @ profile:347
2profile:448 Uncaught TypeError: saveCharge is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (profile:448)`

Comment: Check my code. I told you about the name of the function. Also you have more than one id named "saveCharge". You can have only one id on one page.

Comment: i think you are right.. i have done as per your guide but error change `ReferenceError: values is not defined
    at saveCharge (profile:778)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick `

Comment: Were have you defined the values variable? I don't see it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div class="col-md-6 mb-3 form-group">
  chargeperorder: <input type="text" id ="charge_per_order" name="charge_per_order" class="form-control"><br>
</div>
```

Comment: I am saying, Save button not trigger in with ajax.

Comment: you assig value `undefined` in this `input` that rason ajax dont trigger

Comment: nothing happened.. do you my remote access to check that? @darksihart

Comment: put `alert` in `charge_per_order`

Comment: can you give syntaxt of alert?

Comment: down your `var charge_per_order = $('#charge_per_order').val();` put `alert(charge_per_order);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178954/discussion-between-darksihart-and-kinnari).

Comment: nothing is happened... let chat discussion @darksihart

Comment: hello, what should i do with that.. can you guide me?@darksihart